# Eventmachine: Concurrency

Tags: ruby, concurrency, eventmachine

I have a simple program which receives a connection, does some processing and sends a response back on a standard port. Since this is done synchronous, if one request takes too long, a concurrent request is not handled.

Are Deferrable the way to go to allow multiple requests to be handled simultaneously no matter of any blocking request taking place ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to fork out a new Thread to process your background task, then switch back to the main thread before doing anything EventMachine related. You can do this with the `defer` method:

```
def do_something
  EventMachine.defer do
    do_long_process
  end
end
```

Keep in mind the parts of the application touched by your block will have to be thread-safe, and you will need to be sure to return to the main thread with something like `next_tick` to ensure that all EventMachine operations happen on the proper thread.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on why your request is taking to long, if it's something IO bound like DB query or any kind of request to another server (HTTP, TCP, SMTP, ...) then EventMachine is the way to go.

If that's not your case, can you describe why your requests takes too much time?